# How to plot geographic points on a map with different colours and legend?

Tags: r, gis, rworldmap

So I currently have a map (it's quite ugly, see attached)

[image: Map and points]

I found a way to plot them on a top down view, but I would like to attach different colours and have it as a legend (and maybe zoom in), instead of the lettering on top of the points as shown in the first picture. Can anyone help me with this? Here's the ideal picture, but with a legend and different colours:

[image: The ideal picture, but with a legend and different colours]

```
#libraries

  library(readr)
  library(sp)
  library(rgdal)
  library(raster)
  library(GISTools)
  library(sf)

#col_coor points to be plotted
 SUB        POP      LON   LAT
   <chr>      <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1 mandtii    AK    -156.   71.2
 2 ultimus    NU     -82.5  65.9
 3 ultimus    GR     -70.2  76.5
 4 arcticus   LB     -61.7  56.6
 5 arcticus   NF     -53.6  47.3
 6 arcticus   ST     -69.7  47.8
 7 arcticus   NS     -61.5  45.1
 8 arcticus   NB     -66.8  44.6
 9 arcticus   ME     -68.2  44.2
10 islandicus IC     -22.9  65.4
11 grylle     FI      19.3  60.2

# Convert Lat & Lon data into a SPDF            
col_loc <- sp::SpatialPointsDataFrame(col_coor[,3:4], col_coor)

# Assign a coordinate reference system 
crs(col_loc) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"

 radius <- 75000
  ColBuff<-raster::buffer(col_loc, width=(radius), filename='1000', doEdge=FALSE)


# Plot maximum flight radius polygons on base raster with continent boundaries
  data("wrld_simpl", package = "maptools")                                                                            
  world_map <- crop(wrld_simpl, extent(-180, 180, 35, 90))                                                                   
  plot(world_map, col="grey") 
  plot(ColBuff, pch=20, col="red",add=TRUE)

# Convert WGS84 to Arctic polar stereographic projection (STERE)  
  proj <- "+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=70 +lon_0=-45 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378273 +b=6356889.449 +units=m +no_defs"
  wm_stere <- spTransform(world_map, CRSobj = CRS(proj))
  plot(wm_stere, col="grey")
  cb_stere <- spTransform(ColBuff, CRSobj = CRS(proj))
  plot(cb_stere, pch=20, col="red",add=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure that I understand your questions but do you want to create something like this?

```r
# packages
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.6.1, GDAL 2.2.3, PROJ 4.9.3
library(magrittr)
library(tmap)

# points data
col_coor <- data.frame(
  SUB = c(
    "mandtii", "ultimus", "ultimus", "arcticus", "arcticus", "arcticus",
    "arcticus", "arcticus", "arcticus", "islandicus", "grylle"
  ),
  POP = c("AK", "NU", "GR", "LB", "NF", "ST", "NS", "NB", "ME", "IC", "FI"),
  LON = c(-156, -82.5, -70.2, -61.7, -53.6, -69.7, -61.5, -66.8, -68.2, -22.9, 19.3),
  LAT = c(71.2, 65.9, 76.5, 56.6, 47.3, 47.8, 45.1, 44.6, 44.2, 65.4, 60.2),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

new_crs <- "+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=70 +lon_0=-45 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378273 +b=6356889.449 +units=m +no_defs"

col_coor <- col_coor %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("LON", "LAT"), crs = 4326) %>%
  st_transform(crs = new_crs)

# world data
data("wrld_simpl", package = "maptools")
wrld_simpl <- st_as_sf(wrld_simpl) %>%
  st_crop(xmin = -180, xmax = 180, ymin = 35, ymax = 90) %>%
  st_transform(crs = new_crs)
#> although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_intersection assumes that they are planar
#> Warning: attribute variables are assumed to be spatially constant throughout all
#> geometries

# plot
tm_shape(wrld_simpl) +
  tm_polygons() +
  tm_shape(col_coor) +
  tm_dots(col = "POP", size = 0.33) +
  tm_layout(legend.outside = TRUE, legend.text.size = 1.25, legend.title.size = 1.25)
#> Warning: The shape wrld_simpl is invalid. See sf::st_is_valid
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-02-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

You can read several more details about tmap here: https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/adv-map.html